# Is there a way to make this python selenium code work in headless mode?

Tags: python, selenium, headless

So I've asked this question earlier ([Unable to get selenium (python) to download a csv file which doesnt have a link but only appears after i click the download button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57840487/unable-to-get-selenium-python-to-download-a-csv-file-which-doesnt-have-a-link)) and managed to get this far. I finally realised that the code wasn't working because it was in headless mode.

In my earlier post I also mentioned that I'd try to use requests to get the file but there doesn’t seem to be a link for the `csv` file in this case.

The code basically goes here https://www.macrotrends.net/1476/copper-prices-historical-chart-data, clicks the All Years button, then clicks the Download Historical Data button. and selenium tries to save the file after it clicks.

But like i said it only downloads the file when i'm in normal mode it doesn't seem to work in headless. Is there a reason for this? Is there a way to make it work in headless mode? I've been looking around but i cant find an answer.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

start_time = time.time()

options = Options()

#options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": r"'/home/Documents/testing/macrotrends'",
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
  "safebrowsing.enabled": False
})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/home/chromedriver/chromedriver',options=options)


driver.get('https://www.macrotrends.net/1476/copper-prices-historical-chart-data')

time.sleep(5)
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='chart_iframe']")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
xpath = "//a[text()='All Years']"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
xpath = "//button[@id='dataDownload']"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
time.sleep(10)

driver.close()

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

[screenshot of the website in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTcLy.png)

Comment: After some inspecting, I found that the csv file is not saved somewhere, it is made and exported by JS. You can try using Firefox headless. It might help

Comment: I've just tried to open this webpage in Chrome (by hand, not using selenium), and the download doesn't work at all for me... There's an error in the console, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'goal' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement.document.getElementById.onclick". I'm using Chrome 77 (beta on linux).

Comment: i added a screenshot of a website in chrome in my post, you can take a look. im using Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit) on linux. and the latest chromedriver for that build

Comment: using Google "headless chrome doesn't download" o found issue [How to get Chrome headless to download files](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/chimpy/issues/108). It seems Chrome has (or had) problem to download with headlees.

Comment: I tested Chrome and Firefox on Linux Mint and both don't download in headless mode.

Comment: Any other ideas on how to download this file without a GUI or in headless ? Or does it seem impossible here

Comment: I can download it if I use module `pyvirtualdisplay` to create virtual display and then it uses it to hide window.

Comment: Mind posting the code in an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downloads are disabled by default when in headless mode.  you can allow them by executing a developer tools command like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True 
driver = Chrome(options=options)
params = {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': '/path/for/download'}
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.setDownloadBehavior', params)
# downloads are now enabled for this driver instance
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use module `pyvirtualdisplay` to create virtual display which will be used automatically by `Chrome` or `Firefox` (without `headless`) and it will hide window.

Chrome:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1920,1080))
display.start()

start_time = time.time()

options = Options()

###options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": "/home/Documents/testing/macrotrends", # without `r` and `' '`, only `" "`
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
  "safebrowsing.enabled": False
})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/home/chromedriver/chromedriver',options=options)
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options) # I have chromedriver's folder in PATH so I don't have to use `executable_path`

driver.get('https://www.macrotrends.net/1476/copper-prices-historical-chart-data')
print('[INFO] loaded', time.time() - start_time)
time.sleep(5)

iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='chart_iframe']")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
print('[INFO] switched', time.time() - start_time)

xpath = "//a[text()='All Years']"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
xpath = "//button[@id='dataDownload']"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
print('[INFO] clicked', time.time() - start_time)
time.sleep(10)

print('[INFO] closing', time.time() - start_time)
driver.close()
display.stop()
print('[INFO] end', time.time() - start_time)
```

Firefox:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1920,1080))
display.start()

start_time = time.time()

options = Options()

###options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "/home/Documents/testing/macrotrends") # without `r` and `' '`, only `" "` 
options.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", True)
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="...", options=options)
#driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options) # I have geckondriver's folder in PATH so I don't have to use `executable_path`

driver.get('https://www.macrotrends.net/1476/copper-prices-historical-chart-data')
print('[INFO] loaded', time.time() - start_time)
time.sleep(5)

iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='chart_iframe']")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
print('[INFO] switched', time.time() - start_time)

xpath = "//a[text()='All Years']"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
xpath = "//button[@id='dataDownload']"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
print('[INFO] clicked', time.time() - start_time)
time.sleep(10)

print('[INFO] closing', time.time() - start_time)
driver.close()
display.stop()

print('[INFO] end', time.time() - start_time)
```

Comment: hey thanks for this, method as well, ive never used pyvirtualdisplay before will give it a try